# Component props not updating in shallow render

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a payment component and when I click a button, it should update the component state `isOpen` to true. This works fine in practice but when trying test it via enzyme, it wont update the prop.

The component looks like this:

```
class CashPayment extends Component {
  state = {
    isOpen: false
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Mutation>
        {() => (
          <Fragment>
            <Button
              id="cash-payment-button"
              onClick={this.toggleModal}
            />

            <Modal
              id="confirm-payment-modal"
              isOpen={isOpen}
            >
              ...
            </Modal>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
}
```

So clicking `#cash-payment-button` should toggle the state `isOpen` which should open the modal.

In my test, I want to check the prop of my modal `isOpen` is set to true. But for some reason, the prop doesn't update in the test. However if I console log in my `toggleIsOpen` function, I can see the function gets called and the state updates.

My test is as so:

```
describe("Click Pay button", () => {
    it("Should open confirm modal", () => {

      Component = shallowWithIntl(
        <CashPayment bookingData={bookingData} refetchBooking={refetchBooking} />
      )
      .dive()
      .dive()

      const button = Component.find("#cash-payment-button")
        .props()
        .onClick()

      expect(Component.find("#confirm-payment-modal").prop("isOpen")).toEqual(true)
    })
  })
```

and the results are:

```
CashPayment › Click Pay button › Should open confirm modal
    expect(received).toEqual(expected)
    Expected value to equal:
      true
    Received:
      false
```

Why does the modal component props not update?

Comment: Not sure about this. I think the shallow renderer does not update automatically. You have to tell it to update or get the component again after the click. https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/update.html

Comment: Try `Component.find("#cash-payment-button").simulate('click');`

Comment: Using simulate doesn't make any difference. And trying to `update()` component doesn't do anything either. I even tried getting the component again but to no avail.

Comment: My guess is that the assertion executes and fails synchronously before `Promise.then` callbacks [queued in `PromiseJobs`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) have had a chance to run and set the prop.

Comment: @Stretch0 why don't you just put an assertion on the state? Since isOpen is maintained in the state, onClick you just toggle isOpen in the state. React will take care of re-rendering and passing new prop to child components.

Comment: Can you provide a complete working example that demonstrates the issue?  I can't see enough of your code to provide detailed feedback.  (what is `shallowWithIntl`?, looks like you might be using GraphQL, is that where `Mutate` comes from? etc.)